# getElementByClassName does not work where getElementById does (browser supported)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-events

The script that works:

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
}
var ul = document.getElementById('commandList');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = $(getEventTarget(event)).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    document.getElementById('inputCommand').value = target;
};

var interface = '/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=';
var protocol = 'http://';
var host, command, access, commandUrl;

$('.sendCommand').click(function() {
    host = $('#cameraLocation').val();
    access = $('#cameraAccess').val();
    command = $('#inputCommand').val() + $('#inputParam').val();
    commandUrl = protocol + host + interface + command + access;                
    $('#showUrl').html(commandUrl);
    $('#showResult').attr('src', commandUrl);
});
```

When I'm changing `document.getElementById` to `document.getElementsByClassName` (the element in question has both `ID` and `Class` as `"commandList"`) the script does not work any more, what am I missing?

New script:

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
    }
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('commandList');
ul.onclick = function(event) {
    var target = $(getEventTarget(event)).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    document.getElementById('inputCommand').value = target;
    };

var interface = '/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=';
var protocol = 'http://';
var host, command, access, commandUrl;

$('.sendCommand').click(function() {
    host = $('#cameraLocation').val();
    access = $('#cameraAccess').val();
    command = $('#inputCommand').val() + $('#inputParam').val();
    commandUrl = protocol + host + interface + command + access;                
    $('#showUrl').html(commandUrl);
    $('#showResult').attr('src', commandUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a NodeList of elements, whereas `getElementById()` (and `querySelector()`) return a single node.

To operate on the array-like NodeList you have to iterate over each element contained within the NodeList and specify the actions for each one individually; for example:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('whatever'), function (elem) {
    elem.onclick = function () {
        // do stuff;
    }
});
```

Or:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('whatever'), function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', functionToCallOnClick);
});
```

Comment: I am still unable to get this working, would you mind taking a look: http://goo.gl/LD4JxV - clicking on any command (list element) will fill the "inputCommand" field. Now it is working, using document.getElementById and I am trying to switch to getElementByClassName so I can listen to other elements as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the meantime, found the problem `class="list-unstyled" class="commandList"` instead of `class="list-unstyled commandList"`, the browser gives no error but the JS engine will not appreciate the  mistake. Thanks for the time and answer!

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a HTMLCollection of the matched elements, as multiple elements can share a common class attribute.

You'll have to loop through the returned elements and make relevant modifications to your code to adjust for this.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName